# Can't read parameter in controller, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails project, I want, depending on which link you click, that the resulting created object has a different number.

I have a book and a chapter model, chapter belongs to book. Chapter has an integer attribute called "place".

At the moment, when I click on the link: `http://localhost:3000/1/chapters/new/`
It renders the new.html.erb page and everything works fine.

Now, I added a new route:

```
chapterchapter GET    /:book_id/chapters/new(.:format)/:place     chapters#new
```

This link

```
<%= link_to "Contribute", chapterchapter_path(@book, 5 ) %>
```

will result in:

```
http://localhost:3000/1/chapters/new/5
```

In my controller, I have this line of code:

```
  def new
    @chapter = Chapter.new
  end

  def create
    @chapter = Chapter.new(chapter_params)
    @chapter.book_id = @book.id
    @chapter.user_id = current_user.id
    @chapter.place = params[:place]
```

My problem is, this line of code: `@chapter.place = params[:place]`does not work, since the created chapter returns nil for chapter.place. What do I need to do, that @chapter.place reads the parameter :place? Any advices?

Edit: My database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160117110001) do

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "maxnumchapt"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "min_length"
    t.integer  "max_length"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "chapters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "chaptertitle"
    t.text     "chaptercontent"
    t.string   "author"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.integer  "book_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "place"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Edit 2: It seems, as soon as I press the submit button, the parameter place gets lost:

```
Started GET "/30/chapters/new/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-17 23:39:07 +0100
Processing by ChaptersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"book_id"=>"30", "place"=>"2"}
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]
  Rendered chapters/new.html.erb within layouts/application (36.8ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 53.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started POST "/books/30/chapters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-17 23:39:16 +0100
Processing by ChaptersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"566kl+qg5otw1FGVh0uIoytGxFlF5qp0c4Ws41JhtzSzhqWuND997PltE7LXGiIvEC7A/uqCtg8WMdnNndN/Rg==", "chapter"=>{"chaptertitle"=>"fadfadfaf", "chaptercontent"=>"afddfaf", "author"=>"adfadfa"}, "commit"=>"Create Chapter", "book_id"=>"30"}
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Edit 3: Chapters/new.html

```
<%= simple_form_for([@book, @book.chapters.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :chaptertitle %>
    Mininmum amount of characters: <%= @book.min_length %> Maximum amount of characters: <%= @book.max_length %>
    <div class="counting" ><%= f.input :chaptercontent %>Characters: <span class="count"></span></div><br>
    <%= f.input :author %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    var choosingbar = function( event ){
      $(event.target).parents(".counting").children(".count").text($(event.target).val().length);
    };

    $(".counting textarea").keyup(choosingbar);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: It may be helpful to log the params. Try Rails.logger.debug "====> #{params}"

Comment: Show us your database schema also if you don't mind :)

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN Added database schema (I hope, it's this, what you wanted, I'm an amateur)

Comment: Can you add your form ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BGuimberteau Addet it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be having a ***hidden field*** in the ***form*** for place to catch the `params[:place]` and send it back to `create` action.

```
<%= simple_form_for([@book, @book.chapters.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :chaptertitle %>
  Mininmum amount of characters: <%= @book.min_length %> Maximum amount of characters: <%= @book.max_length %>
  <div class="counting" ><%= f.input :chaptercontent %>Characters: <span class="count"></span></div><br>
  <%= f.input :author %>
  <%= f.input :place, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:place] } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And now in the create action access it like  `@chapter.place = params[:chapter][:place]`

Comment: Works! You saved my day! Thank you so much!